# How I can update security group through Cloudformation without recreating EC2 Instance

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, aws-cloudformation-macro

I have deployed EC2 Instance through Cloudformation and need to update the security group now and I am doing the changes in the existing template but in the Change set I can see my EC2 is getting replaced. How I can modify the security group without recreating the Instance in CF

Tried updating SG in the template but it is recreating EC2

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the changes you to want to make on the [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html) resource. If you change the GroupDescription, GroupName or VpcId properties, an update for these require replacement.

This means a new AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup resource will be created and the old one will be deleted. A new PhysicalId will be created for the AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup resource.

When looking at the [AWS::EC2::Instance SecurityGroups property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroups) update requires replacement. Because a new PhysicalId was generated for the Security Group, this means the sg-idxxxxx passed to the EC2 instance is different causing the EC2 to be replaced.

Properties you can modify on the AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup resource that will not replace your EC2 instance are SecurityGroupEgress, SecurityGroupIngress and Tags because for these an update requires some interruptions or no interruption.

Comment: Once the SG is replaced..WIll I need to go back and associate this SG to all the Instances that referenced the group?